# using a while True loop

Tags: python, while-loop

**Problem 1.**

This problem provides practice using a `while True` loop. Write a function named
`twoWords` that gets and returns two words from a user. The first word is of a
specified length, and the second word begins with a specified letter.

The function `twoWords` takes two parameters:

1. an integer, `length`, that is the length of the first word and
2. a character, `firstLetter`, that is the first letter of the second word.

The second word may begin with either an upper or lower case instance of
`firstLetter`. The function `twoWords` should return the two words in a list. Use
a `while True` loop and a `break` statement in the implementation of `twoWords`. The
following is an example of the execution of `twoWords`:
`print(twoWords(4, 'B'))`:

```
A 4-letter word please two
A 4-letter word please one
A 4-letter word please four
A word beginning with B please apple
A word beginning with B please pear
A word beginning with B please banana
['four', 'banana']
```

---

This is what I have so far, but it keeps asking me the first question over again
even if I have the right word length. What am I doing wrong?

```
def twoWords(length, firstLetter):
    wordLen = input('A 4-letter word please ')
    while len(wordLen) != int(length):
        wordlen = input('A 4-letter word please ')
    word = input('A word beginning with ' + firstLetter + ' please ')
    while word[0] != firstLetter:
        word = input('A word beginning with ' + firstLetter + ' please ')
    return[wordLen, word]
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: You code does not use a `while True` loop nor a `break` statement as the directions state.

Comment: MK C, you may go ahead and post your answer now. The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

```
def twoWords(length,firstLetter):

    firstWord = "" 
    secondWord= ""

    while True:

        firstWord = input('A ' + str(length) + '-letter word please.')
        if length == len(firstWord):
            break
    while True:
        secondWord = input('A word beginning with ' + firstLetter+ ' please')
        if secondWord[0] == firstLetter.upper() or secondWord[0] == firstLetter.lower():
            break
    return [firstWord,secondWord]

print(twoWords(4,'B'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def twoWord(length, firstLetter):
    while True:
       word1=(input("Enter a "+ str(length)+"-letter word please:"))
     
       if len(word1)==int(length):
           break
    while True:
       word2=input("Please enter the word beginning with "+firstLetter+" please:")
       if  word2[0].upper()==firstLetter or word2[0].lower()==firstLetter:
           break
    return word1, word2
```

print(twoWord(5, 'b'))

Comment: 1. Looks too same with an answer already existing
2. In a bad coding style